# Examples about that $\exp(X+Y)=\exp(X) \exp(Y)$ does not imply $[X,Y]=0$ where $X,Y$ are $n \times n $ matrix

Tags: matrices, examples-counterexamples, matrix-exponential

I read the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_exponential

There is a saying that "The converse is not true in general. The equation $\exp(X+Y)=\exp(X) \exp(Y)$ does not imply that X and Y commute."

I would like to know some concrete examples.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Hint**

Consider $X=\begin{pmatrix} \pi i&0\\0&-\pi i\end{pmatrix}$ and $Y=\begin{pmatrix} 0&1\\0&-2\pi i\end{pmatrix}.$

Comment: Note: this answer already gives an example over the reals. Just expand each complex number $a+ib$ into a matrix $\pmatrix{a&-b\\ b&a}$. In other words, if you take $X=\pmatrix{0&-\pi\\ \pi&0\\ &&0&\pi\\ &&-\pi&0}$ and $Y=\pmatrix{0&0&1\\ 0&0&&1\\ &&0&2\pi\\ &&-2\pi&0}$, you get an example in the 4x4 case.