# Why matrix exponential in two different methods not matching?

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-calculus, matrix-exponential

Consider the following matrix:
$$A=\left[\begin{array}{ll}
1 & 1 \\
4 & 1
\end{array}\right]$$ We need to find $e^{At}$.

Method $1.$ Th eigen values of $A$ are $3,-1$.

I have Diagonalized the matrix as: $$A=PDP^{-1}$$ where $P$ is a matrix with first column as an eigen vector corresponding to eigen value $3$ and second column as eigen vector corresponding to eigen value $-1$. We have:
$$P=\left[\begin{array}{cc}
1 & 1 \\
2 & -2
\end{array}\right], D=\left[\begin{array}{cc}
3 & 0 \\
0 & -1
\end{array}\right]$$

Now $$e^{At}=Pe^{Dt}P^{-1}=\left[\begin{array}{cc}
1 & 1 \\
2 & -2
\end{array}\right]\left[\begin{array}{cc}
e^{3 t} & 0 \\
0 & e^{-t}
\end{array}\right]\left[\begin{array}{cc}
\frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{4} \\
\frac{1}{2} & \frac{-1}{4}
\end{array}\right]=\left[\begin{array}{cc}
\frac{e^{3 t}+e^{-t}}{2} & \frac{e^{3 t}-e^{-t}}{4} \\
e^{3 t}-e^{-t} & \frac{e^{3 t}+e^{-t}}{2}
\end{array}\right]$$

Method $2.$ We can write the matrix $A$ as:
$$A=I+B+C$$ where $B,C$ are Nilpotent matrices of index $2$ given by:
$$B=\left(\begin{array}{ll}
0 & 0 \\
4 & 0
\end{array}\right) \text { and } C=\left(\begin{array}{ll}
0 & 1 \\
0 & 0
\end{array}\right)$$

So we have $$e^{Bt}=I+Bt, e^{Ct}=I+Ct$$
So we get
$$e^{Bt}=\left[\begin{array}{ll}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 1
\end{array}\right]+\left[\begin{array}{ll}
0 & 0 \\
4 t & 0
\end{array}\right]=\left[\begin{array}{cc}
1 & 0 \\
4 t & 1
\end{array}\right]$$
Also:
$$e^{Ct}=\left[\begin{array}{ll}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 1
\end{array}\right]+\left[\begin{array}{ll}
0 & t \\
0 & 0
\end{array}\right]=\left[\begin{array}{ll}
1 & t \\
0 & 1
\end{array}\right]$$

Finally we have $$e^{At}=e^{It+Bt+Ct}=e^{It}e^{Bt}e^{Ct}=\left[\begin{array}{ll}
e^{t} & 0 \\
0 & e^{t}
\end{array}\right]\left[\begin{array}{ll}
1 & 0 \\
4 t & 1
\end{array}\right]\left[\begin{array}{ll}
1 & t \\
0 & 1
\end{array}\right]=\left[\begin{array}{cc}
e^{t} & t e^{t} \\
4 t e^{t} & \left(4 t^{2}+1\right) e^{t}
\end{array}\right]$$

So my answers not matching.

Comment: $B$ and $C$ do not commute. Therefore $e^{B+C}\neq ,e^Be^C.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was not true that$$e^{\operatorname{Id}t+Bt+Ct}=e^{\operatorname{Id}t}e^{At}e^{Ct}.$$More generally, it is seldom true that $e^{A_1+A_2}=e^{A_1}e^{A_2}$.

The other method is fine.

Comment: $A_1A_2 = A_2A_1 \rightarrow e^{A_1+A_2}=e^{A_1}e^{A_2}$

Comment: @Frogwilldo Indeed, but $B$ and $C$ do not commute.

Comment: Of course you knew this, t'was for OP :P 

Do you know any counterexample to the converse?

Comment: @Frogwilldo You will find one such example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2036252/446262).

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Is there a way to proceed to find $e^{At}$ in second method. Any hint?

Comment: I don't think that it can be done.